# Sometimes build failed with dexdebug?

Tags: android, gradle, build, dex

I am building my app with Gradle and have added several libraries like Play Services and ChartBoost. I also set `multiDexEnabled true` in my android `build.gradle`. I am using Android Studio IDE and the LibGDX framework.

Yet sometimes it builds successful and other times it fails with the `dexDebug` error. To be clear, I'm not changing anything I just build a couple of times and suddenly it builds successful. What could be causing this?

This has been haunting me for days. I was trying to fix this error but I was not expecting this inconsistent behavior. So I kept changing things around and do a single build, when I finally got things working I got on with my coding and when I wanted to build and got the `dexDebug` error again I started switching things around again, probably breaking the app completely until I un-broke it and got lucky enough to build correctly the first time. Sometimes it takes 3 or 4 attempts to get a successful build.

Projects build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'bouncerandbreak'
        gdxVersion = '1.6.4'
        roboVMVersion = '1.5.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.4.0'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
        //compile files('libs/AdMobAppTracker.jar')
        //compile files('libs/AppTracker.jar')
        compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Android module build.gradle

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('path')
            keyAlias 'DebugKeyStore'
            keyPassword 'keypass'
            storePassword 'storepass'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(path)
            keyAlias 'ReleaseKeyStore'
            keyPassword 'keypass'
            storePassword 'storepass'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.buckriderstudio.bounceandbreak.android/com.buckriderstudio.bounceandbreak.android.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

Comment: please post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @RahulLad It's great to just "know" this can happen. This at the very least took a couple of dozen hours away from me since it is not consistent while afaik it should be consistent.

Comment: @RahulLad Agree with you , I assume version `conflicts` arise this .

Comment: #Menno Gouw Sir : Sometimes same Library causes this , in here you can use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0.` and `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya What do you mean? In "where"?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Changing to those settings somehow crashed `AS` for the first time in my life.

Answer (score 0):

That issue some of your jar files does not compile. You should go to build.gradle (app level) file of your project, and check library dependencies. If you are using jar files, you could try to remove all and add one by one and check. If you do like this you can determine which one of them causes the error.

In my project, I just do the same, and I try to remove all my jar files and replace those from mavin repository as a dependences. And make sure to check their is no version conflicts in "build.gradel" file.

Comment: I still have a hard time finding the correct maven dependencies. Like `ChartBoost`. I get 3 results on maven for it but I don't think there is exists a version I need.